# Is create-react-app npm run build includes devDependencies from package.json?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

To understand the `npm run build` from create-react-app tool I created the following `package.json`

As of understanding the devDependencies will be excluded on the build process but it's included on the build. Please help me to understand

```
{
  "name": "ddd",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/",
  "dependencies": {   
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:cover": "npm run test -- --coverage "
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "jest-cucumber": "^1.0.11",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1764

Comment: Still not clear https://medium.com/@dylanavery720/npmmmm-1-dev-dependencies-dependencies-8931c2583b0c devdependcies should be ignored on build but `npm run build` not ignores